# How to apply Custom Examine Search Index on Nested Umbraco Contents?

Tags: nested, lucene, umbraco, examine

1. I have a doctype `Home` which contains nested doctype `Product`. And i want to be able to search Products.  [image]

   2. I have also created an Examine indexset in ExamineIndex.config as follows:

> ```
>  <IndexSet SetName="ProductsIndexSet" 
>      IndexPath="~/App_Data/TEMP/ExamineIndexes/Products/" >
>         <IndexAttributeFields>
>           <add Name="id" />
>           <add Name="nodeName"/>
>           <add Name="productName"/>
>           <add Name="nodeTypeAlias" />
>         </IndexAttributeFields>
>         <IncludeNodeTypes>    
>           <add Name="homeProduct"/>
>           <add Name="product"/>
>         </IncludeNodeTypes>
>       </IndexSet>
> ```

3. I have created Examine Indexer in ExamineSettings.config as follows:

> ```
>   <add name="ProductIndexer" type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoMemberIndexer, UmbracoExamine"
>            supportUnpublished="true"
>            supportProtected="true"
>            analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer, Lucene.Net"
>            indexSet="ProductsIndexSet"/>
> ```

4. I have created product Searcher in ExamineSettings.config as follows:

> ```
>    <add name="ProductSearcher"
>                type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoExamineSearcher, UmbracoExamine"
>                 supportUnpublished="false"
>                supportProtected="true"
>                 indexSet="ProductsIndexSet"
>                 analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer, Lucene.Net"/>
> ```

But when running the Rebuild Index from **Developer- Examine Management- ProductIndexer**, I am getting 0 Documents in Index.
[image]

I am really not sure how to proceed with examine over nested Contents.
Can anyone help me to set up Examine Search Index on Nested Contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your home node alias is "home" then you need to add that to your Included Node Types on the Index configuration.  `product` doesn't need to be included unless it's also a content node in it's own right.

You may also want to take a look at the article here which outlines an approach to indexing nested content etc.:

https://youritteam.com.au/blog/indexing-content-in-complex-umbraco-data-types